# How can I build a website with fields that any visitor can edit?

Tags: html, web

I'd like to build a website which has the following features:

- There should be a few fields which store numerical values.
- These fields should be editable by anyone who visits the site

A second order feature which would be nice, but isn't necessary

- It would be nice if when multiple people are visiting the site and one visitor updates a value, the webpage reloads for all visitors once the value is saved, updating the value seen for all users

How would I go about implementing the above?

I'm not sure what terms I should even be googling to approach this question, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You're essentially asking "how do I build a web application?"  Basically, at a high level, you pick a web development language or framework or whatever technology you want to start with and, well, start.  For example, if you want to use PHP and MySQL, you start with some introductory tutorials for those.

Comment: Heres a good resource to help get you started learning front-end and back-end languages and frameworks. https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/subject/all

Answer (score 0):

**To your first question:**

```js
const editMe = document.getElementById('edit-me');

editMe.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const editedToInt = Number(editMe.innerHTML);
  if (!Number.isInteger(editedToInt)) {
    // Value is invalid
    editMe.style.border = "2px solid red";
  } 
  else {
    // Value is valid. Do something with it...
    editMe.style.border = "inherit";
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="edit-me" contenteditable>100</div>
```

The user can edit the content and only numbers are allowed.

**To your second question:**

You could save the value which the user has typed in your database. Also you need to use Ajax to check the value in your database every 5 seconds. If the value in your database is different than the value in the DOM, you will replace it.